# Como moverme con la tecla Down y Up dentro de una tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una tabla:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <th>Nombre</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>Juan</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Pedro</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Luis</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Necesito poder hacer click en una fila y con el teclado presionando la flecha hacia abajo moverme a la fila que esta debajo de la antes marcada. Y poder bajar hasta la ultima fila de la tabla sin restricciones.

Necesito tanto subir como bajar en las filas de la tabla.
Si aun no entiendes lo que quiero decir imaginate una hoja de calculo de excel, seleccionas un campo y si presionas la tecla "Down" te movera a la celda que esta debajo de esa. Necesito poder hacer eso pero en vez de moverme por celdas, seria por filas.

Comment: No me ha servido de nada :(

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Intente mas de 16 formas diferentes de hacerlo, pero ya lo solucione.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCION:

```
   IDRow: string = "1";
   ngOnInit(){
     document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
      if (e.keyCode==38){
        //subir
        let j: number = +this.IDRow;
        j--;
        document.getElementById(j.toString()).focus();
      } 
  
      if(e.keyCode==40){
        //bajar
        let j: number = +this.IDRow;
        j++;
        document.getElementById(j.toString()).focus();
      }
   });
 }

 getElementId(i, key = null){
 if(key == null){
   this.IDRow = i.toString();
 }else{
   this.IDRow = i;
 } 
}

<table>
  ....
 <tbody>
    <tr [tabindex]="-1" [id]="i" (click)="getElementId(i)" (keydown)="getElementId(i)">
      <td> ......... </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

ESTO LO HICE YO DE MI MENTE POR QUE NO ENCONTRE INFORMACION QUE ME AYUDARA. No creo que exista una forma mas facil de hacerlo que esta.

TODO CON EL ID de la FILA